# same SQL subquery with WHERE and FROM

Tags: mysql, sql

Using the table below

It can also be easily replaced with an OUTER JOIN whenever a need arises.

The WHERE syntax is more relational model oriented.

A result of two tables JOIN'ed is a cartesian product of the tables to which a filter is applied which selects only those rows with joining columns matching.

It's easier to see this with the WHERE syntax.

```
SELECT Toy_name, Quantity
FROM Toy T,Hire Transaction H, Store S
WHERE S.Store_ID = T.store_id 
AND t.toy_id = H.toy_id
AND t.hire_price = (SELECT max(hire_price) from Toy)
AND UPPER(S.store_suburb = ‘SCARSDALE’)
AND H.hire_date >= ’01/02/2013’
AND H.hire_date <= ’31/03/2015’;
```

I was able to write this. But how can I solve this using a subquery as asked?

Comment: How are you defining the _total hire number_? Or rather, if a toy is hired, but not returned, is that counted towards the _total hire number_? Is the `quantity` per hire to be considered?

Comment: it doesnt say anything about return date so i dont think it has to be consirdered. also as long as toy is hired its hired doesnt have to be returned to actually count. i m not sure how i can use a subquery to combine all hires that is my question

Comment: What I mean about the `quantity` is, in your attempt, you're outputting `quantity` as the _total hire number_ rather than counting the number of `HireTransaction` rows which is how I interpreted _total hire number_.

Comment: have added the actual table to make it a bit clearer. and i think ya i should be adding all the items hired instead of just outputting quantity

Comment: Can you provide the structure as sql statements and some sample data?

Comment: Please don't destroy content on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the sub select, by ordering your result by descending price, and then limiting the output to just one record:

```
SELECT     Toy_name, 
           Sum(H.Quantity) total_quantity
FROM       Toy T
INNER JOIN `Hire Transaction` H
        ON H.Toy_id = t.Toy_id
INNER JOIN Store S
        ON S.Store_ID = T.store_id 
WHERE      upper(S.store_suburb) = 'SCARSDALE'
AND        H.hire_date BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND '2015-03-31'
GROUP BY   T.Toy_id
ORDER BY   T.Hire_price DESC
LIMIT      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT t.toy_name, sum(ht.quantity) quantity, max(t.hire_price) max_p
  FROM toy t
  INNER  JOIN hire_transaction ht on t.toy_id = ht.toy_id
  INNER  JOIN store s on t.store_id = s.store_id
WHERE ht.hire_date between '2013-02-01' and '2015-03-31' and upper(s.store_suburb) = 'SCARSDALE'
group by t.toy_id
having max(max_p)
```

Answer (score 0):

select h.toy_id, sum(h.Quantity) as hire_count from HireTransaction as h where h.hire_date >= ’01/02/2013’
AND h.hire_date <= ’31/03/2015’ group by h.toy_id having h.toy_id = (select toy_id from Toy where hire_price = (select max(hire_price) from Toy) and store_id = (select store_id from Store where store_suburb = 'SCARSDALE')